# Find Character In Primary Key and Update a field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a e-commerce website that uses CMS that uses MS Access 2000 database. The CMS generates the website pages on upload so there's no database online other than Perl files to control the shopping cart. The CMS allows the creation of duplicate products that can be placed elsewhere on the site

I have a table called PRODUCTS in my database. Whereby if a product is a duplicate of the original it contains ! in the primary key

Within the Product table I wish to turn off a setting for all the duplicate products only in the database.

I'm trying to create an SQL statement which would say..

FROM Products
Where Product_Reference contains the character !
Set Can_Be_Ordered_Online to False

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

In regular MySQL it will be something like this:

```
UPDATE Products
    SET Products.Can_Be_Ordered_Online = 0
    WHERE Products.Product_Reference LIKE '*!*';
```

It's hard to find MS Access 2000 docs online these days :(
Luckily, I've found [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php) document about `LIKE` condition, therefore I've just updated my answer. `%` character is MySQL and other SQL-s wildcard, apparently in MS Access 2003 (and with some luck in MSA 2000 too!) the wildcard char are `*`, `#` and `?`.

Nice history lesson :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something like that:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS SET Can_Be_Ordered_Online = FALSE
WHERE Product_Reference LIKE '%!%'
```

If the ! is always at the end or at the start, you can remove one of the %.